# Blade @if / @else returns both statements

Tags: php, conditional-statements, laravel-8, laravel-blade, laravel-livewire

I have an `@if/@else` condition in a Blade file to present different values of a PHP table. The data comes from a Laravel/Livewire controller, and the Blade code that creates the issue is below.

```
@if(!$course->user_limit)
    @if(in_array($course->id, $arrs))
        <x-jet-button wire:click="confirmCourseInterest( {{ $course->id}})"
                      class="bg-orange-500 hover:bg-orange-700">
            {{__('Κάντε κλικ για απόσυρση ενδιαφέροντος')}}
        </x-jet-button>
    @else
        <x-jet-button wire:click="confirmCourseInterest( {{ $course->id}})"
                      class="bg-orange-500 hover:bg-orange-700">
            {{__('Κάντε κλικ για εκδήλωση ενδιαφέροντος')}}
        </x-jet-button>
    @endif
@else
    <div class="flex" id="user_limit_reached">
        {{ __('User Limit Reached') }}
    </div>
@endif
```

The issue occurs on the outer if/else that irregularly returns both if and else statements. The user_limit is false on the field that has the problem. Why does this happen?

[image]

Comment: You'll have to evaluate the building blocks of your logic. Conditions are clear, then check the values provided by the controller.

Comment: The returning values are as expected, the issue doesn’t appear on the same item every time. If I change the sorting then it will be on another line. And the adjacent lines are also correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `@else` to `@elseif` and pass another logic there.

Comment: I have done this already and it presents the same issue... :(